# Getting the position of a digit in a number using recursion

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am current writing a code which returns the position of a certain digit of a user input. I am currently facing a problem where my pointer is not working, which I believe is  due to the recursion function. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rDigitPos2(int num, int digit, int *pos);

int main()
{
    int number;
    int digit, result = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter the digit: ");
    scanf("%d", &digit);
    rDigitPos2(number, digit, &result);
    printf("rDigitPos2(): %d", result);
    return 0;
}

void rDigitPos2(int num, int digit, int *pos) {
    static int count = 0;
    if (num % 10 != digit) { 
    count++; //increment of position
    rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, &pos);

    *pos = count;//returns the position of the digit
}
```

Comment: *rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, &pos)* remove the &

Comment: You need a means to reset the `static count`, otherwise you can use the function only once. You also need to handle the case `num == 0`, which arises when the digit isn't present in the number. And finally, you are calculating the position from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively return the 1 base position your `rDigitPos2`  would be like

```
void rDigitPos2(int num, int digit, int *pos)
{
    static int count = 0;
    if (num % 10 != digit)
    {
        count++; //increment of position
        rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, pos);   //Not &pos

    }
    else
    {
        *pos = count;     //Current position from the last
        while(num!=0)
        {
            num = num/10;
            count++;
        }
        *pos = count-*pos;  //Original position form beginning
    }
}
```

As your first part of recursion find the position from the last, it would be need to find the length of the number then `length-position from last` would be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, &pos);
```

to

```
rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, pos);
```

Since the paramater **(pos)** is already passed to the function in the first call, passing the **(&pos)** in the recursive call will lead to passing of the **address of address of (pos)**.

**Some improvements**

- You will also need to handle properly the case when the **input digit does not appear in the number**
- You are providing the position from **last digit** and not from the start. (Also your count starts from **0** and not **1**)
- It is **redundant** to include the **(digit) parameter** in the function call, as it is a constant.

-Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, &pos);
```

to

```
rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, pos);
```

along with minor details

Answer (score 0):

GCC compiler gives a significant warning, replace  `&pos` with `pos`

```
ss.c:20:31: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'int *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    rDigitPos2(num/10, digit, &pos);
                              ^~~~
```

Humble request, Please do not ignore warnings :)